# How to send an email to a specific recipient from a HTML form and add it to a html table as a record?

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, express

```html
<!-- Placeorder part -->
                <div data-ng-show = "isPlaceOrder">
    <div class = "col-lg-10" style = "margin-top:80px">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class = "panel-heading">Drug Request Mail Sender</div>
    <div class = "panel-body">
    <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-lg-12">
     <form role = "form">
      <div class = "form-group">
       <label>Form</label>
       <input class = "form-control" disabled value = "chief.techmed@gmail.com">
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
       <label>To</label>
       <input class = "form-control">
       <p class = "help-block">reciever.ex@gmail.com</p>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
       <label>Subject</label>
       <input class = "form-control" placeholder = "Drug reorder request for Acetalin 50mg">
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
       <label>Content</label>
       <textarea class = "form-control" rows = "7"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-success">Send</button>
     </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
       <!-- Sent Mail Added Table -->
        <div class = "col-lg-12" style = "margin-top:80px">
        <div class = "panel panel-primary">
        <div class = "panel-heading">Mail History For Selected Drugs</div>
        <div class = "panel-body">
         <div class = "row">
           <div class = "col-lg-12">
            <div class = "table-responsive">
             <table class = "table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
              <thead>
               <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Content</th>
               </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
               <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2016-12-08</td>
                <td>07:23:00</td>
                <td>chief.techmed@gmail.com</td>
                <td>malmal@gmail.com</td>
                <td>Urgent</td>
                <td>We need 20 packs of Anatalyn 500mg</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2017-01-08</td>
                <td>12:23:00</td>
                <td>chief.techmed@gmail.com</td>
                <td>anta@gmail.com</td>
                <td>Immediate</td>
                <td>We need 50 packs of Parasitamol 100mg</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>2017-02-08</td>
                <td>08:23:00</td>
                <td>chief.techmed@gmail.com</td>
                <td>suga@gmail.com</td>
                <td>General</td>
                <td>We need 10 packs of Thylin 50mg</td>
               </tr>
              </tbody>
             </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
      </div>
     <!-- End of Placeorder part -->
```

I'm trying to send an email to a specific recipient through this form which is implemented in html above.And also i want to add that message details to to table which is placed below as a regular record.So can anyone tell me how to do this in an exact way?

I can provide you with any specific parts of my project in order of need.For an example,the node server part which i implemented in nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send an email from an HTML form you need a service that can send SMTP messages. Typically this is handled on the server. Since you're using Nodejs, take a look at [Nodemailer](http://nodemailer.com).

Although less common, it is possible to send email directly from the client. See [SMTPJS](http://smtpjs.com).

Your second question is unclear. What message details are you trying to add to your table?

Comment: All the details which needs to be filled in the email form should get added to the given table as a record.The given table structure is already created with MongoDB.

Comment: Here's a quick start on inserting a record into Mongo using NodeJS: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/quick-start/quick-start/#insert-a-document